# Problem passing vector of templated states to constructor

Tags: c++, stl

For those who are following the saga, I am still trying to define Finite State Machine, states & events in the "proper" C++ way, with templates.

What's wrong with this code?

```
template <typename StateTypeEnum, typename EventTypeEnum>
class Fsm
{
public:
    Fsm(E_subSystems subSystem,
        uint8_t instance,
        const char * const fsmName,
        const std::vector<State<StateTypeEnum, EventTypeEnum> >& states)
    {}
```

where

```
template <typename StateTypeEnum, typename EventTypeEnum>
class State
{
public:
    State(INPUT E_subSystems subSystem,
    StateTypeEnum stateId, 
    const char * const stateName,
    const std::map<Event<EventTypeEnum>,  EventHandlerFunction>& events)
{}
```

The **only** error message is

> no matching function for call to "State<E_callControlStates, E_callControEvents>::State()"  fsm.h   line 98 C/C++ Problem

It looks like the error message refers to a `non-existent` default constructor for state, but why?

`E_callControlStates, E_callControEvents` were the template parameters for declaring an object of Fsm (with no errors).

Obviously, I am overlooking something & making a st00pid n00b mistake, but what? Thanks in advance

---

My bad. Of course it had nothing to do with the code that I was looking at - but then it rarely does, does it?

The class Fsm declared

```
private:    State<StateTypeEnum, EventTypeEnum>  _currentState;
```

when it should have been

```
private:    State<StateTypeEnum, EventTypeEnum> *_currentState;
```

Sorry for misleading you, folks, and thanks for deducing the problem, despite that.

Comment: Try to reduce the code to the smallest subset that still compiles and gives the error. By performing this exercise you will usually find the error. If not this will give you the perfect solution to post here. Without having a compilable example it is very hard to work out the problem unless you had this exact problem 10 minutes ago (or have a good memory).

Comment: ...'that still compiles and gives an error'... that is something hard to come to :) But true, the code is missing important parts there, like the members defined in each class.

Comment: how woudl the members affect it? Just curious (remember, there is one one single compiler error)

Comment: @mawg: if Fsm has a member of type State<> that is not present in the initializer list, the compiler will inject a call to the default constructor in the appropriate position of the initializer list, and that will trigger the error: no default constructor available for that member.

Comment: I'd like to point you out to: Boost.FSM at http://boost-extension.redshoelace.com/docs/boost/fsm/doc/reference.html (it's an interesting read). For your peculiar problem I could not reproduce using gcc 3.4.2. The code here (when I comment out the types I don't know) works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the code you present, but most probably a member of type State that is not being initialized in the initialization list of some constructor, forcing the compiler to default initialize it, and the compiler is not finding the appropriate constructor.

I can only assume that line 98 is in the `Fsm` constructor and that `Fsm` has a member of type `State<...>`.

Comment: +! I am sure that you are on the correct track about constructor problems. yes, line 98 is the FSM constructor.  FSM has a member `std::vector&lt;State&lt;StateTypeEnum, EventTypeEnum&gt; &gt; _states;`

I don't use initializer lists in this code (which is bad, I know), but the STL might.

Comment: The problem is **not** using intializer lists. The vector should not be a problem (unless you request an initial size, or resize it --as compared to push_back elements), but if you had a State subobject that does not have a default constructor, you will be forced to use initializer lists.